# Deploy MapDB to Heroku

Tags: deployment, heroku, dictionary, playframework-2.0, database

Folks,

I'd like to deploy MapDB to Heroku. Any experiences or search directions? Using heroku for the deployment is business requirement but we can change MapDB if not compatible with Heroku. We are using play-framework so any DBMS should be compatible with play and heroku. Any suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying a database to heroku is not quite something that works well. The idea behind heroku is to deploy ephemeral apps, things that don't really have state. And to hold what state is needed *outside* of heroku using plugins. I would suggest that you check out the heroku postgres addon for your DBMS.